# Circuits with pst-circ package Latex

Tags: pstricks

I would like make two resistance in series in this circuit. And just one capacitor in parallel with two resistance (Rct and Zw).

```
\begin{pspicture}(12,12)
\psgrid[subgriddiv=1,griddots=10]
 % Node definitions
\pnode(0,3){A} % resitor
\pnode(3,3){B} % resitor
\pnode(10,3){C} % Capacitor
\pnode(7,3){D}
% Dipole node connections
\resistor[dipolestyle=zigzag,labeloffset=.8cm](A)(B){$R_s$}
\resistor[labeloffset=0cm](C)(D){$Z_{w}$}
\resistor[dipolestyle=zigzag,parallel,parallelarm=-1,labeloffset=-.7cm](B)(D){$R_{tc}$}
\capacitor[parallel,parallelarm=1,labeloffset=.9cm](B)(C){$C_{dc}$}
\end{pspicture}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define only *one* parallel element:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-circ}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](12,6)
 % Node definitions
\pnodes(0,3){A}(3,3){B}(10,3){C}(7,3){D}
% Dipole node connections
\resistor[labeloffset=0cm](C)(D){$Z_{w}$}
\resistor[dipolestyle=zigzag,labeloffset=-.7cm](B)(D){$R_{tc}$}
\capacitor[parallel,parallelarm=1,labeloffset=.9cm](B)(C){$C_{dc}$}
\resistor[dipolestyle=zigzag,labeloffset=.8cm](A)(B){$R_s$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @FabioLima If this answer solved your problem, you should accept it (click on the gray ✓ symbol left of the answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
\begin{pspicture}(10,10)
%\psgrid\[subgriddiv=1,griddots=10\]
 % Node definitions
\pnode(0,3){A} % resitor
\pnode(3,3){B} % resitor
\pnode(9,3){C} % Capacitor
\pnode(6,3){D}
% Dipole node connections
\resistor\[dipolestyle=zigzag,labeloffset=-.7cm\](A)(B){$R_s$}
\capacitor\[dipolestyle=chemical,parallel,parallelarm=1,labeloffset=.9cm\](B)(C){$C_{dc}$}
\capacitor\[dipolestyle=chemical,labeloffset=-0.7cm,parallelarm=2\](D)(C){$Q_{if}$}
\resistor\[dipolestyle=zigzag,parallelarm=-1,labeloffset=-.7cm\](B)(D){$R_{tc}$}
\end{pspicture}
```

[image]